# How do I switch to a different Google account in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Previously it was possible to switch between different accounts easily on Gmail.

Now they suggest me only one account (of my wife) and without any option to re-login with mine.

How can I add in my account and switch to it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Gmail, click your profile icon in the top right hand corner and click "Add Account".

[image]

Sign into the other account, and you can then switch back and forth between the two accounts by clicking the profile icon again.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a new profile for your wife.

Go to `chrome://settings` (type that into the location bar) and click *Add new user*. After that the new user will be able to switch to another email address.

Comment: Would be nice if you could add a screenshot of the _Add new user_ window.