# Log in to different Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account

How do I log in to a different Gmail account?  We have three Gmail accounts and every time I try to open a Gmail account the same one is opened.  Why can't I enter the Gmail account that I am trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either:

- Log out of the current account, and *then*
  log in to the new account, or;
- Log in to an additional account, using the **Add Account** button, as
  described in
  [How do I switch to a different Google account in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52047/how-do-i-switch-to-a-different-google-account-in-gmail)